# How can I force Enter key to move right?

Tags: windows-8.1, spss, enter

I am not in Excel, and SPSS (the app I am using) does not have this config option. I am on Win 8.1. Is there a way to force Enter key (numeric keypad) to move right?

Answer (score 0):

Enter always goes down, but Tab will go across and wrap at the last variable.